# Unknown jsf behavior

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I have these scenario. An xhtml page with a datatable where I have a button to jump to another page:

```
<p:dataTable id="tablaSections" value="#{preventSectionMB.listSections}" var="item" paginator="false">
<p:column headerText="" style="width:90px;">
<p:commandButton action="listElementsSectionPrevent.xhtml" icon="fa fa-edit" title="Edit">
    <f:param name="faces-redirect" value="true"></f:param>
    <f:param name="idPrevent" value="#{item.idPrevent}"></f:param>
    <f:param name="idSection" value="#{item.idSection}"></f:param>
</p:commandButton>
```

It works fine, but I don´t know why before opening the new page (listElementsSectionPrevent.xhtml) it read seven times the preventSectionMB.listSections property from the managed beans

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: could you add the source of the next page?

Comment: You can set process="@none" on the commandbutton to avoid submitting the form values and the listSections method will not be called.